# Primefaces messages "for" argument not working with bean validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bean-validation

I have a bean validation according to:

```
@Min(value = 0)
@Max(value = 1000000)    
private int kilometres;
```

In my facelet I have:

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />

<p:outputLabel for="kilometres" value="Kilometres" />
<p:inputText id="kilometres" value="#{bean.vehicle.kilometres}">
     <p:ajax event="change" />
</p:inputText>
```

When i have this it works fine, except that all messages for all field ids will be shown. I would like to specify for each field, like this:

```
<p:messages for="kilometres" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />
```

However, when I add the for="kilometres" option, then no validation messages is shown. Have I missed something or is it a bug?

Best regards

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: What scope is your backing bean?

Comment: Is `<p:message/>` worked? Are you still having problem with showing separate validation messages?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I running Mojarra 2.1.6 and PrimeFaces 3.4.1.  p:message for="kilometres" is working, but not p:messages for="kilometres", and with 1 field only. Very strange. Ended up with using p:growl, and that is working like a charm. EDIT: I am using SessionScoped scoope

Comment: I update my answer with an example which uses component specific `p:messages`. I think this is what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `<p:message/>` component to show validation messages for each input component separately:

```
<p:outputLabel for="kilometres" value="Kilometres" />
<p:inputText id="kilometres" value="#{bean.vehicle.kilometres}">
    <p:ajax/>
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="kilometres"/>
```

Showcase: [AJAX - Validations](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxValidations.jsf)

**UPDATE**

In order to show multiple message for a given component (with `p:messages`) you need to specify the relevant component ID in `for="kilometres"` and in your backing bean too:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

context.addMessage("kilometres", new FacesMessage("Message 1"));
context.addMessage("kilometres", new FacesMessage("Message 2"));
```

Comment: Hi akoskm! Thanks for your support! That works, but that forces me to implement a wrapper around the model or around every field in the model actually. For now, I only have "vehicle" as a field in my "bean". => private Vehicle vehicle; + setter and getter. Thats it. How do you solve this problem? Thanks again =)

Comment: If this worked for the original problem I suggest you to mark this post as answer. You should also open a new question regarding your current problem and the discussion should continue there.

Comment: I should have stated that there has not been any problem to create new FacesMessages explicitly, what I would like to do is to only use a facelet page, and a bean with fields with bean validation annotations. Nothing else. Thanks anyway =)

Comment: @kungcc you can definitely do simple validations and provide custom messages using only annotations, like `@NotNull(message = "This value may not be null")`. See [Package javax.validation.constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html).